# Generic Func: Key path value type '[T]' cannot be converted

Tags: swift, combine

I'm playing with Combine to learn it and improve my reactive programming skills, and I'm trying to create some generic class that convert data to my *T* type

I have this error, and I don't understand why

> *Key path value type '[T]' cannot be converted to contextual type 'T'*

```
class Fetcher<T: Codable>: ObservableObject {
    private var task: AnyCancellable?
    @Published var result = [T]()

    init<T: Codable> (type: T.Type) {
    guard let url = URL(string: "https://api.example.com") else { return }
    task = URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
        .map{$0.data}
        .decode(type: T.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
        .receive(on: DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background))
        .replaceError(with: T.self as! T)
        .assign(to: \.result, on: self)
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Does the URL give you an array of `T`s or just one `T`? Also, that `replaceError` looks like it will most definitely crash.

Comment: You need to [edit] your question to include all relevant code as text, using proper code formatting - and not as a screenshot -, in the form of a [mcve] in order to make the question on-topic.

Comment: @DávidPásztor edit done.

Comment: @Sweeper The url gives me an array of T's. Why it would crash?

Comment: when you'd decode it, you may need to decode it as an array, eg. `.decode(type: [T].self, decoder: JSONDecoder())` rather than a single item – probably the same applies to the `.replaceError(...)` line as well.

Comment: .decode(type: [T].self, decoder: JSONDecoder())

Comment: Consider that the generic `T` can be both a single object and an array. And you should not suppress errors in a Codable context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the URL gives you an array of `T`s, you should decode an array, rather than a single `T` in the `decode` call. This line

```
.decode(type: T.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
```

should be:

```
.decode(type: [T].self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
```

That `replaceError` call is going to crash your app, as `T.self` is not a `T` (it's a `T.Type`), and you are force-casting. Since you are receiving an array, a logical choice for a value to replace errors with, is the empty array `[]`:

```
.replaceError(with: [])
```

Also, remove your generic parameter on `init`:

```
init() {
```

Comment: I changed to [T].self, and changed .replaceError(with: []). Now Xcode is saying "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context" in task = ...

Comment: @swifthing I just found it. You have declared two `T`s. Gosh this is really hard to spot.